# Is $\mathbb Z$ of finite presentation over $\mathbb F_1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I know that there are several proposals for theories of the "field with one element", such as Deitmar's, based on "commutative monoids with zero" and [monoid schemes](https://www.emis.de/journals/BAG/vol.49/no.2/b49h2dei.pdf), or Lorscheid's, based on [blueprints](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1745).

This is not my field at all (I am a theoretical computer scientist), so my understanding of this is extremely superficial and I was not able to figure out whether, within any of these theories, the integers are an algebra of finite presentation over the field with one element. Is this the case?

If the current theories do not provide an answer (for example because it is not clear what "finitely presented" even means), is there a best guess?  I mean, in a fully working theory of the field with one element, is this expected to be true or not?

Comment: I think it is important to note that, for classical fields $F$, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an algebra over $F$ (since there is no subring of $\mathbb{Z}$ which is a field). I am not sure about $\mathbb{F}_1$.

Comment: @walkar yes, but, if I understand correctly, $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb Z$ is supposed to be an affine variety over $\mathbb F_1$, which means, dually, that there should be a homomorphism $\mathbb F_1\to\mathbb Z$, making $\mathbb Z$ an $\mathbb F_1$-algebra (in fact, by initiality of $\mathbb Z$ every commutative ring whatsoever should be an $\mathbb F_1$-algebra).

Comment: I think you might consider copying this over to MathOverflow, since $\mathbb{F}_1$ is definitely a research-level topic and might be beyond the scope of MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there is at least one proposed theory including a "field with one element" in which the answer is **yes**.

In his [approach to Arakelov geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2030), Nikolai Durov suggests to take commutative finitary monads as generalized commutative rings.  This is motivated, among other things, by the existence of a fully faithful embedding of commutative rings into commutative finitary monads, sending a commutative ring $R$ to the monad of $R$-modules.  So the integer ring $\mathbb Z$ becomes the monad of abelian groups. The definition of $\mathbb F_1$ is taken to be the monad of pointed sets.

It is well known that finitary monads are the same thing as Lawvere theories, which is helpful here because it gives an immediate way of presenting these generalized rings and, in particular, of saying whether a given generalized ring is of finite presentation over another.  With the above definitions, it is easy to see that $\mathbb Z$ is of finite presentation over $\mathbb F_1$.  This is explicitly stated in §4.5.16 of Durov's thesis.

I am still unable to figure out whether any other approach to $\mathbb F_1$ allows for a definition of "finite presentation" and, in that case, what the answer to my question would be in that theory.